# UITabBarController, UINavigationController, and UIViewController spacing in Swift Language

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift, bounds

I'm having persistent issues getting my layouts correct with an application which launches with a UITabBarController, while each tab is populated with a UINavigationController with a root subclassed UIViewController:

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let controller_1 = subclassed_view_controller()
    let controller_navi_1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: subclassed_view_controller);
    //repeat for 2-4

    let view_controllers = [controller_navi_1, controller_navi_2, controller_navi_3, controller_navi_4]
    let tab_bar_controller = UITabBarController()
    tab_bar_controller.viewControllers = view_controllers

    //set up each tab's aesthetics (image and name)

    self.window!.rootViewController = tab_bar_controller;

    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

for some reason, the bottom of my content for each view controller is covered by the tab's in swift. I'm pretty committed to doing this programatically and not through IB, but I am clearly missing something with inferred layouts.

Thanks for any clarification, especially regarding a method that doesn't involve using the "-20 or -44" logic; I find it too hacky for my liking.

*Note 1: I have tried manipulating .bounds and .clipsToBounds without success*

*Note 2: The same issue exists in objective-C, with comparable code*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom view controller, set:

```
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
```

This will let the OS know not to extend your controller content under the bars.